# for loop if else returns 0 insteads of -5 to 5

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to quantize close price and previous 5 days close price into 1 to -1, where if today's close is greater returns 1 else return -1. The sum of the quantization should return from the range -5 to 5, yet my plot of sum return all 0. what is the problem here?

```
ct = close
r=0
s=0
for i  = 1 to 5
cp = close[i]
    if  (ct - cp) > 0
        r=1
    else 
        r=-1
    s := s + r   
plot(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `:=` operator when you want to re-assign a value into a variable (`r` in your case).

Change your code to this:

```
ct = close
r=0
s=0
for i  = 1 to 5
    cp = close[i]
    if  (ct - cp) > 0
        r:=1
    else 
        r:=-1
    s := s + r   
plot(s)
```